# HexaPDF glyphs missing as of Version 0.20.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, pdf

I'm using HexaPDF to read a file with an AcroForm and fill in this form's fields using the following code:

```
@acro_form.field_by_name(fieldname).field_value = value
```

Up until version 0.20.1 this worked fine. As of version 0.20.2, I get this error: HexaPDF::Error (Glyph for "2" missing) on trying to generate the document. The glyphs for all numbers, and for all lower case letters except a, b, and c cause this respective error.

This problem only occurs in my dev setup on Windows 11, not on Linux.

@gettalong or anyone else who might be able to help: Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @gettalong I figured out the problem:

Some of the text in data/hexapdf/encoding/glyphlist.txt appears to be automatically processed by Windows, inserting line and page breaks in this file which should not be there, and causing other changes to the file's encodings.

I resolved it by editing the above file as follows:

- Remove extra paragraph and line breaks and potential invisible characters on entries for controlFF, controlVT and controlSO
- Set codes (the part after the semicolon) for controlSUB to blank
- Remove blank space on "controlBEL; ", changing this line to "controlBEL;"
- Ensure there is a blank space on space, i.e. the line must be "space; ", not "space;" and ensure there is no additional invisible character there.

Save the file and restart server.